# Ubuntu Software Center is not allowing me to download software when I try to install something

Tags: software-center, xfce

I recently have gotten myself an Acer C720 Chromebook. This is the device I am currently using. On this device I have XFCE4 installed. I installed Ubuntu software center so that I may in turn get software. I did so using the apt-get install command. It runs fine, It's just that when I select a software I would like to install nothing happens. Even after repeatedly clicking, nothing happens. I am only allowed to get certain software from the apt-get install command in the terminal, and sometimes some of that software isn't installed correctly. I would really like a solution to this problem.

Comment: Are you running basic Ubuntu or Xubuntu? Or are you running some sort of Chromebook OS / Chrome OS?

Comment: Aside from Xubuntu I am running Chrome OS.

Comment: So you boot into Chrome OS, and then start Xubuntu inside of Chrome OS somehow?

Comment: I use the crosh terminal to boot into XFCE4.

Answer (score 0):

Don't blame Ubuntu!  I too have an acer chromebook.  It is stored elsewhere or I'd rattle off my model number to you.

Like you I did the sideways Ubuntu installation through terminal so that I can have Ubuntu and Chrome essentially running concurrently, accessible via some key combination, something like ctrl-alt 1 or 2 or something.  It works remarkably well but I've proven it to have certain limitations.

For one thing I discovered that even though I was sort of able to install WINE, it would not actually run.  I suspect that if Chrubuntu were installed in place of chrome, it would work but sharing the chrome kernel, it would not.  Trust me, I tried very very hard.

Realizing as I do that the type of Ubuntu we have installed is sharing a non Ubuntu kernel essentially owned by a manufacturer which appears to be in competition with microsoft, and to a lesser degree, other linux derived operating systems, it is not remotely surprising that Google chose to curtail our freedoms a bit.